# send to port on server

Tags: iphone, xcode

If I open up a port on our server to listen out for incoming messages (ie - strings of text), how can i send those messages? are their any example codes out there that are useful?

I have downloaded a few sample projects but none seem to do i want.

what code is used to specify the ip address and port number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) you wil find exactly what you need.

It is a wrapper class called `AsyncSocket`; to connect you just send it the string with the ip and an int with the port.

It will do all the work on ints own.

To send info you just turn your string into NSData if I remember correctly.

It has a very easy to follow sample so you should be up and running in about 20 min.

Comment: Thanks for this!Is that for iOS devices? the sample code i downloaded is for MAC.

Comment: @Sam Parrish: I have been using it on several of my iOS apps with no issues, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Look up any tutorial text on networking.
For instance, there are a bunch of [echo server implmentations](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Echo_server) at rosettacode.